# Scala reflection behaves differently on interpreter and compiled code

Tags: scala, reflection, interpreter

I have

```
trait T
class C extends T
```

compiled to .class files. And the piece of code below to load them:

```
val loader = ScalaClassLoader fromURLs (/* List[URL] */)
val classB = loader.tryToInitializeClass("B") getOrElse (/* throw something */)
println(classB.asInstanceOf[Class[_]].getInterfaces)
```

When I run the loading code in Scala interpreter, the result is

```
res1: Array[java.lang.Class[_]] = Array(interface T, interface scala.ScalaObject)
```

but when the loading code compiled into .class files and run I got

```
[Ljava.lang.Class;@1b8e059
```

Please tell me how to have the compiled loading code yield the result as fine as on the interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you executed the println in the interpreted session? Because the first result you write looks suspiciously  like the interpreter displaying the result of just
`classB.asInstanceOf[Class[_]].getInterfaces)`, without the println (res1 is very telling)

On the other hand, the cryptic [Ljava.lang.Class;@1b8e059 is the toString of an Array. So your problem is just that, toString. If you do something like `println(yourResult.mkString(", "))`, that should be much better. In the REPL, results displays are better than plain toString

Comment: Thank you, this is the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

`Array(interface T, interface scala.ScalaObject)` and `[Ljava.lang.Class;@1b8e059` are the same type of object, just printed out in different ways.

Array[Class[_]] gets printed out like [Ljava.lang.Class;@1b8e059 when you call the toString on it.

Try the following:

```
scala> val f = Array[Class[_]](classOf[Map[String, String]], classOf[Object])
f: Array[java.lang.Class[_]] = Array(interface scala.collection.immutable.Map, class java.lang.Object)

scala> f.toString
res1: java.lang.String = [Ljava.lang.Class;@407e62
```

The REPL is being helpful when it prints out the value of an expression. If you want to print out a useful string in your compiled code, for example:

```
scala> f.toList.toString
res4: String = List(interface scala.collection.immutable.Map, class java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
res1: Array[java.lang.Class[_]] = Array(interface T, interface scala.ScalaObject)
```

does not come from your `println` expression, it comes from the REPL. If an entered expression returns anything except `Unit`. The REPL prints the name, type and result of the `toString` method of that object.

```
name: Type = from toString
```